# Outputting RSSI WiFi signal strength to console

Tags: android, wifimanager

I am trying to output the RSSI signal strength of my home access point onto the console. So far I've added the receiver to the manifest.xml:

```
    <receiver android:name="newAndroidApplication"  android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION"/>
            </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>
```

Then I added the following class to my main activity:

```
public class MyWifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
          if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
              WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
              if(wifiInfo != null) {
                  int dbm = wifiInfo.getRssi(); 
              }
          }

      }
}
```

So where do I go from here? I feel that I am very close to completing the output of the dBm to the console so just need a little help with this part.

Answer (score 0):

May be a little bit late, but I got it with this filter :

```
.RSSI_CHANGED_ACTION
```

instead of :

```
.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION
```